# Azure Web Jobs, Azure Service Bus Queue Trigger prevent message from getting deleted

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, azure-webjobs, azure-servicebus-queues

I am looking into setting up a web job trigger to read message from service bus queue. What would be the best practice to implement a retry logic in case of any errors handling the downstream systems.

Would we be able to throw an exception so that the message will not be deleted from the queue and will be retried after certain time period?

Appreciate your feedback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to define retry logic explicitly. When the message is de-queued from service bus , it gets invisible from queue for certain time period (lock time default 30secs , you can configure it). You try to process the message , if it gets successful you simply call BrokeredMessage.CompleteAsync which means i am done and mark this message as completed. If you have some problem in down stream you can abandon the message by calling BrokeredMessage.AbandonAsync . This will unlock the message and the message appears back in the queue. The message will be picked up by the worker again and process it. Until you get successful or reach the max retry limit after which the message is send to dead letter queue.

Comment: How ServiceBusTrigger works

The SDK receives a message in PeekLock mode and calls Complete on the message if the function finishes successfully, or calls Abandon if the function fails. If the function runs longer than the PeekLock timeout, the lock is automatically renewed.

Service Bus does its own poison queue handling which cannot be controlled or configured by the WebJobs SDK.

Comment: does the above mean by default the message is removed form the queue when received by the trigger binding method. is there a configuration entry to change this behavior..thanks

Comment: In services bus increase the lock time to match the processing time of your worker. e.g. your worker takes 5 mins to complete , but your message lock time in your services bus is 30 secs , the message will reappear in message queue while the other copy of message is still being processed by worker. So increase your services bus message lock time that you consider is sufficient for worker to complete.

Comment: I thought by default the queue trigger bind method will dequeue the message as soon as it is able to successfully read. question is how to reappear the message in case of any error when calling downstream systems

Comment: your worker process the message and before that it locks (peek) it . Failure or success either case you have to mark the status of message i.e. Complete/Abandon . If there is problem in down stream and you are not happy , simply mark it abandon. If you don't give any status the message will reappear in the queue once peek lock is expired.

Comment: got it.. sorry I was missing the point that the trigger binding method should be declared to accept brokered message as follows         public static void SBTopicListener2(
            [ServiceBusTrigger(TopicName, QueueNamePrefix + "topic-2")] BrokeredMessage message,
            TextWriter log)